# How to do port forwarding with two interfaces using iptables?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, port-forwarding, router

I have a debian box with two interfaces wan and lan(192.168.0.1). On lan:80 I have a site that must be accessed from local network. Also I need this site to be accessed from wan:777. This is my iptables rules:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i $LAN -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i $WAN --dport 777 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.1:80
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.0.1 --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

However, it doesn't work. It works only if I remove `-i $LAN` fron INPUT. I mean this way:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i $WAN --dport 777 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.1:80
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.0.1 --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

However, it is a bad way, because site is now also on wan:80 and this is not what I want. What is my mistake?

Comment: LAN variable is interface address or interface name?

Comment: @realpclaudio $LAN is interface name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer on [Russian Linux forum](https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/admin/15531527) :

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i $WAN -p tcp --dport 777 -j MARK --set-mark 0x1234
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i $WAN --dport 777 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.1:80
iptables -A INPUT -m mark --mark 0x1234 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try  `iptables -A INPUT -d 192.168.0.1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`

It is wrong way to use  `iptables -A INPUT -i $LAN -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`

Answer (score 0):

If webserver is listening on port 80 then you need to enable that port on INPUT chain.
NAT is not enough if destination port is not allowed to be reached, that's why it's working if you do not restrict source interface.

Since destination is the same, can't you just define another virtualhost on WAN:777 port?